# Apollo Server 4: typescript errors during build process in production mode

Tags: node.js, typescript, apollo, apollo-server

I've migrated Apollo Server from v3 to v4.

It works everything fine but I am not able to build the project in production mode because
there was several typescript errors into `@apollo` package. These are the last two left:

```
[tsl] ERROR in /home/xxx/projects/dashboard-api/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/ApolloServer.ts(238,53)
      TS2345: Argument of type 'ApolloServerOptions<TContext>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithStaticSchema<TContext>'.
  Type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithGateway<TContext>' is not assignable to type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithStaticSchema<TContext>'.
    Type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithGateway<TContext>' is not assignable to type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithTypeDefs<TContext>'.
      Property 'typeDefs' is optional in type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithGateway<TContext>' but required in type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithTypeDefs<TContext>'.
```

or

```
[tsl] ERROR in /home/xxx/projects/dashboard-api/node_modules/@apollo/server/src/ApolloServer.ts(1140,7)
      TS2322: Type 'string | DocumentNode' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'DocumentNode' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "incremental": true,
        "lib": ["ES2020"],
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"],
            "@/test/*": ["test/*"]
        },
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "./node_modules",
        "./node_modules/*",
        "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    ]
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
                use: 'ts-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
    },
    target: 'node',
}
```

webpack.production.js

```
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.ts')],
    externals: [nodeExternals({})],
    mode: 'production',
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
})
```

package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/graphql-iso-date": "^3.4.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.41",
        "@types/pg": "^8.6.5",
        "@types/type-is": "^1.6.3",
        "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.40.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.40.1",
        "apollo-server-testing": "^2.25.3",
        "aws-sdk-mock": "^5.8.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^8.25.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
        "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
        "husky": "^8.0.1",
        "jest": "^29.2.0",
        "jest-mock-extended": "^3.0.1",
        "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0",
        "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
        "nock": "^13.2.9",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/datasource-rest": "^4.3.2",
        "@apollo/server": "^4.0.1",
        "@hubspot/api-client": "^7.1.2",
        "@sentry/node": "^7.15.0",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^7.15.0",
        "@shopify/shopify-api": "^5.2.0",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.6.2",
        "apollo-datasource-http": "^0.21.0",
        "apollo-server-caching": "^3.3.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1234.0",
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "graphql": "^16.6.0",
        "graphql-import-node": "0.0.5",
        "graphql-iso-date": "^3.6.1",
        "graphql-tools": "^8.3.6",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "pg": "^8.8.0",
        "sanitize-html": "^2.7.2",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.production.js",
    }
}
```

node version is v16.16.0

Is there any workaround to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved those two issues left removing this import

```
import { ExpressContextFunctionArgument } from '@apollo/server/src/express4'
```